# Can we use same slugname for category and tag name in Wordpress version 4.4.2?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add same `slugname` for category and tagname in wordpress.

**But it returns an error like this:**

> could not insert term in to the database

I am using `Wordpress Version 4.4.2`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why you want to use same slug name ? you can you that one name twice for other post.

Comment: this is not possible, everything is filtered based on the slug in wordpress. You can disable unique in the wp_options table, but this will just always show the first slug available.

Comment: @Christophvh Thanks i will check your sugestion.

Comment: @Christophvh may i know which option name i have to set disabled in wp_options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

**That's what I did:**
- Articles -> Categories -> Added new category "Example"
- Articles -> Tags -> Added new tag "Example"

I have two working url's:
**/category/example**
**/tag/example**

So, the slugs are the same 'example', the url's are different.
If you're talking about the same url that's also possible, you'll have to use a template with a custom WP_Query.

1. Create a simple page in the WP backend -> "Example"
2. Create a template file with the same slug as the page you've created: page-example.php
3. Insert a custom WP_Query were you grab a category + tag with the same slug. Check the code below for the query parameters.

   ```
   <?php
   // SETUP WP_QUERY
   $posts = new WP_Query(array(
       'category_name' => 'example',
       'tag' => 'example'
   ));

   // START LOOP
   if ($posts->have_posts()) :

       // DO STUF

   // END LOOP
   endwhile;endif;

   // RESET POST DATA
   wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   ```

Comment: I wan't to just add category and tag with same slugname from backend.

Comment: It worked for me. Maybe you need a fresh install of wordpress. Try  to deactivate your plugins to Check if there are some conflicts.